# Labeling texts with Amazon Sagemaker Ground Truth using Amazon Mechanical Turk workforce

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, labeling, amazon-ground-truth

Using Amazon SageMaker Ground Truth, is it possible to specify a spanish language fluency for Mechanical Turk workers in order to label texts written in spanish language? If not, how does SageMaker Ground Truth select Mechanical Turk workers to correctly label a text written in a specific language?

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your question. I'm the product manager for Amazon SageMaker Ground Truth. It is not currently possible to require Spanish language fluency for MTurk workers via SageMaker Ground Truth. If you do want to ensure your workers are fluent in Spanish language, we suggest choosing one of the third-party vendors with Spanish language fluency as your workforce. Please feel free to reach out directly if you have any questions.